Cannot import LAS/LAZ files in QGIS 3.40.1 ubuntu 24.04
When importing a LAS/LAZ File into qgis it says:
LAS and LAZ files cannot be opened by this QGIS install.
This QGIS build does not include the PDLA library dependency required for opening LAS or LAZ point clouds.
However pdal itself and its python wrapper is installed on the system.
Qgis Version: 3.34 and 3.40.1
OS: Version Ubuntu 24.04 Noble

we reinstalled Qgis
we installed a different Version of Qgis (3.34 and 3.40.1)
installed pdal using the module import inside qgis
tried what was recommended in the official Doku


Please consider using https://qgis.org/ubuntugis to be able to install pdal and all QGIS dependencies.
